# Next JS Roles and Permissions Best Practice

Tags: next.js, roles, next-auth

I'm using Next 14 and Next-Auth for authentication (credentials), which I have set up and is working.

My User model has an array one or more Roles and an array of one or more Permissions through those roles. For simplicity, it looks something like this:

```js
{
  id: 'USR_123',
  roles: ['manager', 'editor'],
  permissions: ['manage_clients', 'edit_pages', 'update_settings' ]
}
```

What's the best way to ensure that the roles and permissions for the current user are available when a user is logged in as I may need to check these for authorisation on each request?

I thought about adding it to the [session callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback) in next-auth. What limit (if any) is on the amount of data passed with this? If a user had 5 roles and around 80 individual permissions, would this be ok? Or is there a better way?

Comment: dpstudio, did you fine any better solution for it, and how did you implemented. did you use server action or api ?